# Drupal Front end Form with fields with option to add More Fields

Tags: entities

I want to create a Form in the frontend, so user can able to add the data in the form and submit the data. Then i have to display all the data submitted by the user using that form. Just like a Internal Messaging system. I want a Add Reports Form and i want to list all the reports in a page ( View Reports). I planned to create a content type ( Reports), After that i will be able to add the fields. Upto this i know how to do. But i want to know how to have a row with three fields with add button, then if user click on the button,  i want to append a new row with same three fields. Just like Multiple Image upload. I have screenshot. In screen one, i have a add button above a row with three fields. In the screen two which is taken after clicking the "add button" , It displays the same add button with two rows with same three fields .

Screen 1 : 
[image]

Screen 2 :

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "Name of Stocklists", "Sales as on Date", and "Closing Stock Value" are all CCK fields, you should be able to do this using Field Collection (https://drupal.org/project/field_collection).

1) Install Field Collection

2) Create a field collection field on your Report content type. Use the embedded widget. Be sure to make the field multi-value / unlimited values.

3) Go to admin/structure/field-collections and click Manage Fields for the field collection you created.

4) Add the 3 stock text fields to the field collection.

5) Now on the Report add/edit forms, you'll have the "Add Another Item" button.

To align the fields in a row, you should be able to use CSS. To make the button a +, you should be able to use hook_form_alter() or hook_form_report_node_form_alter().

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Can you use IEF on the front end? Also, would it reference the parent node?